# How do I write an xpath using class?

Tags: xpath, selenium

Anyone please help me to construct the shortest xpath for the below one. I am writing the automation script using selenium.

This is the link I would like to click on from selenium:

```
<a class="LiveChat" onclick="openLiveChat()" title="Live Chat" href="#nogo">
  <span class="ChatIcon"> </span>
  <span>Live Chat</span>
```

And following is the xpath I got from firebug:

```
/html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/a[2]/span[2]
```

I tried the following command which doesn't seem to work:

```
selenium.click("//a[@class='LiveChat']/span");
```

Comment: `//a[@class='LiveChat']` try this for test, if failed maybe your element is in iframe, or it get from ajax request.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? Is selenium not able to *find* the element or do the effects of the `click` not happen? My guess is that you're not seeing the effects of the click, and I'm guessing it's because you're clicking on the `span` and the javascript is on the `a`. Try it with `//a[@class='LiveChat']` instead.

Comment: Give a try with this ==> selenium.click("//a[@class='LiveChat']//span"); as required span is not the immediate child of <a> tag you should use double slash before span tag

Answer (score 1):

As i can see,**Live chat** is a link...

There is a much better option in selenium to click on links,you can use the following statement,

`driver.findElement(By.linkText("Live Chat")).click();`

Moreover,you should try and reduce the use of `xpath` in your code, a better option would be `cssSelectors`.....

[you can click here for more info](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/)

Comment: Question was using `Selenium` and not `Webdriver`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `Xpath` to click on the `Live Chat`

```
//a[@class='LiveChat']/span[contains(.,'Live Chat')]
```